# Model `select by partition key in Cassandra` in BigTable

Tags: select, cassandra, partitioning, bigtable

What would the equivalent of modeling a `select by partition key in Cassandra` be in BigTable?

For example; if I had a Cassandra table

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  empID int,
  deptID int,
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (empID, deptID));
```

I can query

```
SELECT deptid FROM emp WHERE empid = 104;
```

In BigTable; I think this is equivalent to adding columns to a Row?
If so is that a relatively standard design pattern?

Or if not; is there another pattern that can be used?

Thanks
Brent

Comment: empid is your partition key, so your `SELECT deptid FROM emp WHERE empid = 104;` will return all the rows (deptIDs of them) in that partition which is a normal way to do that. I am not really clear on your question.

Comment: I know more about the Bigtable side than Cassandra.  Is the partition key equivalent to a row key?  If so, and you're using the HBase API, you do: `Result r = table.get(new Get(YOUR_ROW_KEY).addColumn(FAMILY, QUALIFIER))`.  YOUR_ROW_KEY would be the byte[] equivalent of 104, and QUALIFIER would be the byte[] equivalent of "deptid"

Comment: @SolomonDuskis would that be considered a standard way of tracking something like 'employees in a department'? Or would it be somewhat of an anti-pattern; and there is a better way to model it?
The goal being to be able to look up - all employee's in a department; when needed

And understanding that the column shouldn't get too too wide.

Comment: Bigtable has a single index.  If your primary use case is department, then create a key of department#emp_id.  Then you can scan with a prefix of department#.  If you have multiple use cases, you either sacrifice performance and keep one table, or create a table per case.

Comment: To clarify, you can filter Bigtable results by any column or value, but there will still be a range scan or a full table scan.

Comment: in your table empID is your partition key, and each one has a row per deptID that also has name. http://www.sestevez.com/sestevez/CassandraDataModeler/ might help you visualize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly addressed in the comments. Bigtable does not have separate partition key and primary key concepts and only has a single index.

Your example you would probably want to make both your employee ID and department ID part of your row key. Keys are stored lexicographically and you can use prefixes to do more efficient subscans, so you would need to determine whether to concatenate either employee ID followed by department ID, or vice versa.

This is somewhat akin to the reverse domain name pattern and you may want to review the guidance suggested here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#types_of_row_keys